# MultipeerConnectivity MCPeerID does not conform to Codable

Tags: ios, json, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I'm writing a simple P2P chat program and thus far I've been storing MCPeerID's `displayName` property as a string in my model to determine who to send a particular message to.  On each send operation, I search through the `connectedPeers` array and copy the MCPeerID into a receiver list whenever the displayName matches the string I have in my model.

This can be problematic in the case where two peers have the same name.  And I'm also not satisfied with having perform a search for each send. So I'm trying to use MCPeerIDs directly in my model.  However, Xcode complains that MCPeerID does not conform to Encodable nor Decodable, and I'm not sure how to fix this.

My model represents a topic that maintains a list of participants as well as a log of who said what.  Thus, I can sync a new participant when they join and update existing participants when new messages are added.  My model looks something like the following:

```
import Foundation
import MultipeerConnectivity


class Task : Codable {
    var uuidStr: String = UUID().uuidString
    var topic : String
    var history : [String] = []
    var users : [MCPeerID] = []

    ...

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case uuidStr
        case topic
        case history
        case users
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(uuidStr, forKey: .uuidStr)
        try container.encode(topic, forKey: .topic)
        try container.encode(history, forKey: .history)
        try container.encode(users, forKey: .users)
    }

    ...

}
```

(I haven't shown the standard init() as this is not where the problem lies.)

After looking at the documentation, I see a method with the signature `MCPeerID.init?(coder: NSCoder)` and `func encode(with: NSCoder)` but I'm not sure how to specify the NSCoder parameter.  Any help on how to serialise the `users` property would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 4):

There seem to be a few issues here (p2p is a complex subject):

### 1. identifying users (business level),

The peer name MCPeerID(displayName: ) is not the peer identifier, it's just aimed at the human viewer (e.g. chatroom users). Point 3) below shows a way how a peer can include other user info when advertising their presence.

### 2. identifying peers (network level),

The framework (MC) creates a unique peer id for you and recommends the app re-use (ie. persist & reload) across app launches ([MCPeerID - official docs - example objetive-c using NSUserDefaults storage api](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity/mcpeerid)).

### 3. sharing peer session info (session level)

In your model, you're serialising the Task, fine (though no mention of what format, .xml, .plist, .json etc), but I don't see why you're wanting to serialise these MCPeerIDs? 
Each peer on connecting is supposed to re-use their own peerID, and, optionally, if they wish to advertise additional info to potential peers they could provide a dictionary with info about the business-user behind the peer object e.g:

```
myAdvertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: reusableLocalPeerID, discoveryInfo: ["uuidStr" : "my-user-id-here"], serviceType: "my-tasks-app")
```

([MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity/mcnearbyserviceadvertiser/1407102-init)).

### 4. separating concerns (data level)

I would separate the framework (MC) from business model (Task, User ...) , to something like this:

```
class Task: Codable { var users: [User] ... }
class User: Codable { uid:String ...}
struct PeerRecord: { var peer:MCPeerID, var user_id:String, var name:String ... }
var foundPeers:[MCPeerID]
var connectedPeers:[String:PeerRecord] // e.g. ["a-user-id": PeerRecord(peer: ...)]
```

### 5. serialising

Apple example at point 2) above shows how to serialise MCPeerID using UserDefaults api.

Generally, when one extends Codable, one also expects to use an encoder (JSON, XML etc) somewhere in the app, 
passing to this encoder's .encode(...) method the object in question e.g:

```
func storeTasks(tasksCodable:[Task]) -> Bool {
  if let encoded_in_data_format = try? JSONEncoder().encode(tasksCodable) {
      UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded_in_data_format, forKey: "tasks")
      return true
  }
  return false
}
```